# How to fix numpy floating-point operations producing inexact results?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, comparison, floating-accuracy

I need to rebuild absolute frequencies from relative frequencies knowing the sample size.

This should be easy but absolute frequencies and sample size are `numpy.int64`, relative frequencies are `numpy.float64`.

I know floating-point decimal values generally do not have an exact binary representation and we can experience some loss of precision. This seems to be the case, the floating-point operation is producing unexpected results and I can't trust the rebuilt absolute frequencies.

Sample code to replicate the error:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

absolutes = np.arange(100000, dtype=np.int64) #numpy.int64
sample_size = absolutes.sum() # numpy.int64
relatives = absolutes / sample_size #float64

# Rebuilding absolutes from relatives

rebuilt_float = relatives * sample_size #float64
rebuilt_int = rebuilt_float.astype(np.int64)

df = pd.DataFrame({'absolutes': absolutes,
                   'relatives': relatives,
                   'rebuilt_float': rebuilt_float,
                   'rebuilt_int': rebuilt_int})

df['check_float'] = df['absolutes'] == df['rebuilt_float']
df['check_int'] = df['absolutes'] == df['rebuilt_int']

print('Failed FLOATS: ', len(df[df['check_float'] == False]))
print('Failed INTS:', len(df[df['check_int'] == False]))
print('Sum of FLOATS:', df['rebuilt_float'].sum())
print('Sum of INTS:', df['rebuilt_int'].sum())
```

Is it possible to solve the problem using numpy without casting every number to a decimal?

Comment: Is your issue that the multiplication is inexact, or that the comparison is inexact? Basically where do you want to do the rounding (or coercion)?

Comment: [`numpy.isclose()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) is an fp-aware inexact comparison that does what you want, and is vectorized.

Comment: The issue is the multiplication is inexact. Rounding before converting to int64 as suggested by Warren does the job. Good point in using numpy.isclose() for comparison.

Comment: your current rounding is worse than `numpy.isclose(, atol)`. You have gross errors for half the floats because `astype(np.int64)` rounds-down e.g. df['rebuilt_float'][5] became 4.999999999999999 which `astype(np.int64)` seems to convert to 4. Are you seeing that?

Comment: Yes I see it in Jupyter: df['rebuilt_float'][5] is 4.9999999999999991 and df['rebuilt_float'][5]).astype(np.int64) converts it to 4, which is not what I expected. But if you round before the conversion np.round(df['rebuilt_float'][5]).astype(np.int64) gives 5, which is the result I want.

Comment: Right, but it seems the builtin `numpy.isclose(, atol)` would be simpler (and probably faster) than all that. Also less error-prone. We have this neat (not-very-well-known) builtin, why hack around it and risk errors if user forgets to round before coercing to int before comparing....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you round the rebuilt values before converting to integers, you get zero failed ints.  That is, use

```
rebuilt_int = np.round(rebuilt_float).astype(np.int64)
```

The output is then

```
Failed FLOATS:  11062
Failed INTS: 0
Sum of FLOATS: 4999950000.0
Sum of INTS: 4999950000
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.isclose(df['absolutes'], df['rebuilt_float'], atol=.99999)`

[`numpy.isclose()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) is an inexact fp-aware comparison. It has an extra args `atol` and `rtol` for relative and absolute tolerance.

You can see by changing `atol` how many rounding errors you get rid of:

```
>>> len(np.where( np.isclose(df['absolutes'], df['rebuilt_int'], atol=.99999) == False )[0])
0
>>> len(np.where( np.isclose(df['absolutes'], df['rebuilt_int'], atol=.5) == False )[0])
2767
>>> len(np.where( np.isclose(df['absolutes'], df['rebuilt_int'], atol=1) == False )[0])
0
```